# Hibernate @SequenceGenerator allocationSize ignored by JPA GenerationType.AUTO

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We are using Hibernate with JPA annotations, configured as shown below. When we use GenerationType.AUTO, the allocationSize is ignored and hibernate logs show sequence.nextval for every insert.

Changing it to GenerationType.SEQUENCE as below works as expected. But this is not portable across other databases. Is this a bug? Or is there some other configuration that we need to set?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MYOBJ_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MYOBJ_SEQ", sequenceName = "MYOBJ_SEQ", allocationSize = 100)
@Column(name = "MYOBJ_PK", length = 11)
private Integer id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible and portable way to generate identifiers is to use a database table, e.g.:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "id_generator")
@TableGenerator(allocationSize = 100, name = "id_generator")
@Column(name = "MYOBJ_PK", length = 11)
private Integer id;
```